# Issue running React App on Django server with webpack

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, webpack, django-middleware

I am building a web-application using Django as the backend and want to implement a ReactJS framework frontend. Each application that I have as of now runs properly, independently of one another. I have also implemented webpack and it appears to configure properly, as it will run my ReactJS application on the localhost. Being new to webpack (and web-development in general) I am unsure how to get React to run on the Django local server (127.0.0.1:8000). I understand from the many forums I've read through that the javascript files need to be bundled and then read into the django app. Below are the relevant files:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "package.json",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is the private repository for the USA Baseball analytics team.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "SET NODE_ENV=development babel src -d lib",
    "build-prod": "SET NODE_ENV=development babel src -d lib",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/USAB-Analytics/BaldEagle.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/USAB-Analytics/BaldEagle/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/USAB-Analytics/BaldEagle#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^0.8.3",
    "yarn": "^1.7.0",
    "react-prop-types": "^0.4.0",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.77.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "3.0.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.10",
    "jsx-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "react": "^16.4.0",
    "webpack": "^4.10.2",
    "webpack-bundle-tracker": "^0.3.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.4",
    "webpack-command": "^0.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
  },
  "keywords": []
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require("path");
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
//var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';

module.exports = {
 mode: 'development',
 entry: './frontend/src/index.js',
 output: {
   filename: 'bundle.[hash].js'
 },
 devtool: 'inline-source-map',

 module: {
   rules: [

     // First Rule
     {
       test: /\.(js)$/,
       exclude: /node_modules/,
       use: ['babel-loader']
     },

     // Second Rule
     {
       test: /\.css$/,
       use: [
         {
           loader: 'style-loader'
         },
         {
           loader: 'css-loader',
           options: {
             modules: true,
             camelCase: true,
             sourceMap: true
           }
         }
       ]
     }
   ]
 },
 plugins: [
   new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
     title: 'Custom template',
     template: './webapp/templates/webapp/home.html',
   })
 ],
 devServer: {
   host: 'localhost',
   port: port,
   historyApiFallback: true,
   open: true
 }

};
```

**frontend/src/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './css/main.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import {HomePage} from './components/HomePage.js'
import {Bios} from './components/Bios.js'
import {Bio} from './components/Bio.js'
import {NavBar} from './components/NavBar.js'
import {TeamsList} from './components/TeamsList.js'
import {TOSBios} from './components/TOSBios.js'
import {NT18Bios} from './components/NT18Bios.js'
import {CNTBios} from './components/CNTBios.js'
import {NT15Bios} from './components/NT15Bios.js'

class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    var styles = {
      'marginLeft': '210px'
    }
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="col-sm-10">
          <NavBar />
            <div style={styles}>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
              <Route path="/bios/:id" component={Bio} />
              <Route path="/bios/" component={Bios} />
              <Route path="/teams/tos/:id" component={Bio} />
              <Route path="/teams/cnt/:id" component={Bio} />
              <Route path="/teams/nt18/:id" component={Bio} />
              <Route path="/teams/nt15/:id" component={Bio} />
              <Route path="/teams/cnt/" component={CNTBios} />
              <Route path="/teams/nt18/" component={NT18Bios} />
              <Route path="/teams/nt15/" component={NT15Bios} />
              <Route path="/teams/tos/" component={TOSBios} />
              <Route path="/teams/" component={TeamsList} />
            </Switch>
            </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**webapp/templates/webapp/home.html**

```
<!-- {% extends "webapp/header.html" %} -->
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>React with Django</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you used render_bundle function from webpack_loader? You've imported webpack_loader but not used render_bundle to load react!

Answer (score 0):

These shouldn't be running on the same server. If you are looking to connect them you should be able to create config files and say if production the url I hit is xx.com/users otherwise if it is development it is localhost:8000/users. Why would you need both to run on the same server?

Comment: We need to be able to run it through the django template due to our app being hosted on a python hosting site. In order for it to work, the frontend application should bundle through webpack and then be served by the django app.

Answer (score 0):

We use [django-webpack-loader](https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader) to render our webpack bundles in a django template (for a Vue app but it's the same fundamental idea).

Comment: We have been trying to implement django-webpack-loader. How would you recommend we approach this here?

Answer (score 0):

You've configured your webpack for development mode. It means that you run the webpack development server. But you need to build your front-end application into a bundle and then use this bundle for your server side. Just remove the `devServer` section. Also, you can erase this `process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';` and change the `mode` to `production`. This operation will set your `process.env.NODE_ENV` to `production`(https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/).

If you need to test your app in development mode you can add `proxy` to package.json with the address of your back-end and run front and back separately.

**Solution:**

Add an npm command:
`"build:prod": "<your_build_command> && mv <output_path>/index.html <path_to_backend>/<app_name>/templates && mv <output_path>/* <path_to_backend>/static"`

Add this to your Django app settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Comment: I did the steps you said and it compiled, but nothing changed.

Comment: after the compilation, you need to add the compiled file to your Django app index.html

Comment: We think we are doing this currently, but clearly we are not. How would you recommend doing this?

Comment: Nothing difficult. Just make the bundle, move it to the /static/ folder in Django and add the link like this to your main template `<script src="{% static 'bundle.js' %}"></script>`

Comment: @Spencer I've added another possible solution to my answer

Comment: Implemented the changes you suggested but now run into the following error: `The system cannot find the path specified.npm ERR! package.json@1.0.0 build-prod: ``SET NODE_ENV=development babel src -d lib && move ./webapp/templates/webapp/home.html ./webapp/templates && move bundle
.[hash].js/* ./webapp/static``
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the package.json@1.0.0 build-prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.`

Comment: @Spencer remove [hash] as bash doesn’t know what is hash. You can whether use static name for your bundle or use something like bundle.*.js for the npm command

Comment: We changed node_env=development to =production and we changed [hash] to bundle.*.js, but we are still receiving the same error message.

Comment: It seems that you cannot use command with “-“. Replace it with “:”

Comment: It doesn't appear to change anything on our end. We're receiving the same error either way.

Comment: your problem is in syntax. Do you use windows?

Comment: Yea on a windows machine

Comment: I can't test it on Windows. But the idea is so. Generate the bundle what is `babel src -d lib` in your case. Then move the generated bundle in Django static folder. And move the generated .html to Django templates folder. On every request to the Django you must render this template except the API requests. The exception you have is a syntax error.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation that makes sense. I found the syntax error, Windows uses '\' instead of '/' so it couldn't find the files. At this point it shows that the appropriate files were moved. But the react still does not display.

Comment: Checkout browser’s network panel. Is there a request for your bundle?

Comment: On the Django side I don't see any request being made. If you meant the React side, I receive: `%7B%%20static%20'bundle.js'%20%%7D:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
localhost/:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/%7B%%20static%20'bundle.js'%20%%7D' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.` in the inspector

Comment: That being said, although the errors appear, the react app seems to run as expected